# Как можно правильно оформить обработчик запросов в HTTP-сервере?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

Имею такой вот хттп-сервер на питоне (весь код будет ниже). Передо мной стоит задача: необходимо при загрузке определённой страницы (скажем index.html) делать определённые действия (скажем, вызывать time.sleep() и "засыпать" на какое-то время). Насколько я понимаю, необходимо правильно описать do_GET() метод. Но каким таким образом? Может ли кто-нибудь направить меня на пусть истинный?

```
import http.server, socketserver, os
import _thread as thread


PORT = 8000
DIR = '/home/root/dir'
ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path.startswith('/kill_server'):

            def kill_me_please(server):
                server.shutdown()
            thread.start_new_thread(kill_me_please, (httpd,))
            self.send_error(500)


class MyHTTPServer(socketserver.TCPServer):

    def server_bind(self):
        import socket
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)


os.chdir(DIR)
server_address = (ADDRESS, PORT)
httpd = MyHTTPServer(server_address, Handler)

try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
finally:
    httpd.server_close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path.endswith('/test.html'):
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        self._set_headers()
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
```

а вот так